# It selects links of a particular user from DB but the error is if '%.png' is not found it displays all the other files of every user on database

Tags: php, mysql

`links` is the table name and `link` is the column name.

```
$gettingemail = $_SESSION['email'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM links WHERE username='".$gettingemail."' AND 
link LIKE '%.png' OR link LIKE '%.jpeg' OR link LIKE '%.exif' OR link LIKE '%.tiff'";
```

Comment: are you sure about user thing as I can see the check in your query

Comment: `SELECT * FROM links WHERE username='".$gettingemail."'` is it working?

Comment: not a syntax error. It's a logical error.

Comment: yes it does. @devpro

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM links WHERE username='".$gettingemail."' AND 
(link LIKE '%.png' OR link LIKE '%.jpeg' OR link LIKE '%.exif' OR link LIKE '%.tiff')";` try this

Comment: or try %value% like `$sql = "SELECT * FROM links WHERE username='".$gettingemail."' AND 
(link LIKE '%.png%' OR link LIKE '%.jpeg%' OR link LIKE '%.exif%' OR link LIKE '%.tiff%')";`

Comment: Thankyou @devpro . The 1st one worked.

Comment: which one is worked second solution or first?

Comment: The 1st one. @devpro

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You just need to add your OR clause in one condition as:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM links WHERE username='".$gettingemail."' 
AND (link LIKE '%.png' OR 
     link LIKE '%.jpeg' OR 
     link LIKE '%.exif' OR 
     link LIKE '%.tiff')";
```

Here i am using OR condition as one block `(condition OR condition)`:

```
(link LIKE '%.png' OR link LIKE '%.jpeg' OR link LIKE '%.exif' OR link LIKE '%.tiff')
```

**Side Note:**

Also note that, your query is open for SQL injection, for preventing SQL injection you can use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Also note that, don't know which extension are you using for execute your query, as per your tag if you are using `mysql_*` than note that, its deprecated and closed in PHP 7.

Comment: glad to help u, @SimranjitSingh: dont forget to accept the answer this will help to other just click on the left tick.

Comment: This is an appallingly wreckless solution. See SQL injection.

Comment: @Strawberry: yes it is, and he can use prepared statement for preventing SQL injection.

Comment: I look forward to your amended answer